# How to iterate through all keys within dic with same values one by one with sequence

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on some text file which contains too many words and i want to get all words with there length . For example first i wanna get all words who's length is 2 and the 3 then 4 up to 15 for example
Word = this , length = 4
hate :4
love :4
that:4
china:5
Great:5
and so on up to 15

I was trying to do with this following code but i couldn't iterate it through all keys one by one .And through this code I'm able to get just words which has the length 5 but i want this loop to start it from 2 to up to 15 with sequence

```
text = open(r"C:\Users\israr\Desktop\counter\Bigdata.txt") 

d = dict() 

 for line in text:  
    line = line.strip() 

    line = line.lower() 

    words = line.split(" ") 
    for word in words:
        if word not in d: 
            d[word] = len(word) 

def getKeysByValue(d, valueToFind):
    listOfKeys = list()
    listOfItems = d.items()
    for item  in listOfItems:
        if item[1] == valueToFind:
            listOfKeys.append(item[0])
    return  listOfKeys
listOfKeys = getKeysByValue(d, 5)

print("Keys with value equal to 5")
#Iterate over the list of keys
for key  in listOfKeys:
     print(key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is:

1. Changed the structure of your dictionary: 
   In your version of dictionary, a "word" has to be the key having value equal to its length.
    Like this:
   `{"hate": 4, "love": 4}` 
   New version: 
   `{4: ["hate", "love"], 5:["great", "china"]}` 
    Now the keys are integers and values are lists of words. For instance, if key is 4, the value will be a list of all words from the file with length 4.
2. After that, the code is populating dictionary from the data read from file. If the key is not present in the dictionary it is created otherwise the words are added to the list against that key.
3. Keys are sorted and their values are printed. That is all words of that length are printed in sequence.
4. You Forgot to close the file in your code. Its a good practice to release any resource being used by a program when it finishes execution. (To avoid Resource or Memory Leak and other such errors). Most of the time this can be done by just closing that resource. Closing the file, for instance, releases the file and it can thus be used by other program now.

```
    

    # 24-Apr-2020
    # 03:11 AM (GMT +05)
    # TALHA ASGHAR

    # Open the file to read data from
    myFile = open(r"books.txt") 
    # create an empty dictionary where we will store word counts
    # format of data in dictionary will be:
    # {1: [words from file of length 1], 2:[words from file of length 2], ..... so on }
    d = dict() 

    # iterate over all the lines of our file
    for line in myFile:
        # get words from the current line  
        words = line.lower().strip().split(" ")
        # iterate over each word form the current line
        for word in words:
            # get the length of this word
            length = len(word)

            # there is no word of this length in the dictionary
            # create a list against this length
            # length is the key, and the value is the list of words with this length
            if length not in d.keys(): 
                d[length] = [word]
            # if there is already a word of this length append current word to that list
            else:
                d[length].append(word)

    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        print(key, end=":")
        print(d[key])

    myFile.close()
```

[image: Output of the Program]

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of code is correct, dictionary **d** will give you all the unique words with their respective length. 
Now you want to get all the words with their length, as shown below:

```
{'this':4, 'that':4, 'water':5, 'china':5, 'great':5.......till length 15}
```

To get such dictionary you can sort the dictionary by their values as below.

```
import operator
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

sorted_d will be in the below format:

```
{'this':4, 'that':4, 'water':5, 'china':5, 'great':5,......., 'abcdefghijklmno':15,...}
```